# How do I build a gem that allows for linking against different native libraries at install time?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies, native

Nokogiri allows for this by specifying the libraries in the install command:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-lib=/home/joe/builds/lib 
                    --with-xml2-include=/home/joe/builds/include/libxml2 
                    --with-xslt-lib=/home/joe/builds/lib 
                    --with-xslt-include=/home/joe/builds/include
```

I did a little digging through Nokogiri's source to try to find out how they allow for those options to get passed down from the command to the actual build/installation.

I noticed the use of Rake::ExtensionTask as well as mini_portile, however their use seems to be limited to cross compiling on Windows systems in their code.

Is there some bit of code I can throw in my gem to allow users to specify the library they want to link against at install time? How did nokogiri allow for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using the [`dir_config`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/Object.html#method-i-dir_config) method of the [`mkmf`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/index.html) library.

The [`gem install`](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_install) command uses any arguments after `--` as arguments to the build command, so they get passes to your `extconf.rb`.

Note you still need to use [`have_library`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/Object.html#method-i-have_library) or [`find_library`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/Object.html#method-i-find_library) in order to actually link to the library.